# How to migrate contacts to Teams?

Tags: powershell, import, microsoft-teams, skype-for-business, microsoft-graph-teams

I wanted to migrate my SkypeForBusiness contacts to MS Teams. I have already exported my contacts to txt file and here is the problem that i cannot find any option to import it to Teams as contacts. Using its API in PowerShell i can create team and add my contacts as users but it is not what i wanted to do. However this API does not provide functionality to add my email list which i have in txt file to my Teams contacts. Is there any possibility to import my contacts with groups to Microsoft Teams ?

Would appreciate every answer. 
Thanks

Comment: This is not a PowerShell code issue, which is what we are here for, but a why can't MS Teams or its API do this. If Teams does not provide the hook, then it's a catch22. I don't use Teams, but my query would be, can you do this using the Teams GUI, if not, then again, you have a catch22. What have you searched for? After a quick search, there are several articles discussing ways to get Skype contacts into Teams, even directly via the Teams GUI.

Answer (score 2):

If your admin migrates you from SfB, your contacts are migrated to Teams automatically. Perhaps your admin can do this for you.

Since this is how most users start using Teams for telephony, there hasn't been a huge demand for a standalone contacts import/export feature.

There is a feature request on UserVoice you can vote for if you like: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/33116188-import-groups-contacts-from-skype-for-business